# I need to print a two dimensional char array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I need to create a boardgame and
the [output of the array needs to look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hsdw6.png):

[image: desired output]

[But the output of my code looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cd6UT.png):

[image: current output]

How can i get rid of those signs and make it look like the output I need?

And this is my code for it:

```
private char[][] boardMatrix;

    public TryingSth() {
        boardMatrix = new char[3][3];
//        boardMatrix[0][0] = 'H';

        for (int i = 0; i < boardMatrix.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < boardMatrix.length; j++) {
                if (i==0 && j==0){
                    System.out.print('H');
                } else if (i ==2 && j==2){
                    System.out.print('G');
                }else
                boardMatrix[i][j] = '_';
                System.out.print(boardMatrix[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
```

Comment: step 1 is writing code that can compile. Except for a missing return type for your method (and the neglect of naming conventions) your code does exactly what it should do

Comment: But why do you not store your G's and H's in that boardMatrix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're printing `boardMatrix[i][j]` on every loop iteration. However, if you look closer, you'll see that you **set the value of `boardMatrix[i][j]`** only when it is equal to `_`. Therefore when you want to print 'H' or 'G', the value of `boardMatrix[i][j]` it not initialized, there is just some random bytes, so this character is printed as a crossed box (character with this code is non-printable).

You need to change lines `System.out.print('H');` and `System.out.print(G');` to `boardMatrix[i][j] = 'H';` and `boardMatrix[i][j] = 'G';` accordingly.

Comment: How did I not think about that . Thanks a lot for the help. Appreciate it